# popup a message before jwt session end using angular app

Tags: angular, jwt, popup

i'm facing a problem, i would like to popup a message to a user 1 min before session end.

for that  i've imagine a scenario, where i'm setting a **timeout** until 60 second before end session and in the **timeout** i have a callback that will generate the popup. the problem is that, i don't know where to do this **timeout**. i did it in a **sharedService** that i've call in all my component(in the onInit() method ) in the projet so that it will be called each time, when the user change a page but this solution is not efficient.

any idea how i can do it correctly or a any framework or documentation on the topic.

```
///SharedService

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionTimerService {
  private jwtExpirationTime: Date;
  private timer: number;

  setExpirationTime(expirationTime: Date) {
    this.jwtExpirationTime = expirationTime;
  }

  startSessionTimer(minutesBeforeExpiration: number, callback: () => void) {
    if (this.jwtExpirationTime) {
      const popupDisplayTime = this.jwtExpirationTime.getTime() - minutesBeforeExpiration * 60 * 1000;

      clearSessionTimer();

      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        callback();
      }, popupDisplayTime - Date.now());
    }
  }

  clearSessionTimer() {
    if (this.timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
  }
 popupMessageFunction() {}
}

********************************************************

//i call this logic in all my component
//
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionTimerService } from './session-timer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mon-component',
  templateUrl: './mon-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mon-component.component.css']
})
export class MonComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private sessionTimerService: SessionTimerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const jwtExpirationTime = ;

   
    this.sessionTimerService.setExpirationTime(jwtExpirationTime);

    
    this.sessionTimerService.startSessionTimer(5, () => {
      this.afficherPopup();
    });
  }

 
}
```